# unable to merge 2 macros together

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

What is does now :
There are 2 sheets "requisition form" " price schedule"
When I enter values in column D of price schedule and hit the button click to generate file the Column D and F is copied and pasted in requistion form from G27 and H27.

What I am trying to do is:
make another button called "Consolidate" and when I click on that it should copy the total amount "G183" in price schedule and paste it in G27 of requisition form.

Error:

when I am clicking generate file it is doing it properly. But as I click clear values and enter the values again in Column D of price schedule and click on consolidate it is not copying and pasting the total amount. gives me error #REF!. I tried giving the values of the cells but as soon as I click clear button it is erasing the formula selected on it and showing me the above error.

Also can anyone help me in " how to put a constant $1 value in column H27 when I click consolidate button.
so basically when I click consolidate button it should copy the total amount "G183" from price schedule sheet and pste it on G27 in requisition form along with a constant $1 in H27.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Worksheets("Requisition Form").Range("A27:H34").ClearContents
 Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rDest As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Worksheets("PRICE SCHEDULE")
    Set wsDest = wb.Worksheets("Requisition Form")
    Set rDest = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    If rDest.Row < 26 Then Set rDest = wsDest.Range("G27")

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    With wsData.Range("D14:F" & wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
        If .Row < 13 Then GoTo CleanExit     'No data
        .AutoFilter 1, ">0", xlFilterValues 'Filter on column C for values >0
        Intersect(.Worksheet.Range("D:D,F:F"), .Offset(1)).Copy 'Copy filtered values in columns C and E only
        rDest.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues    'Paste values only to destination
        .AutoFilter 'Clear filter
    End With

CleanExit:
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub

Sub Clearcells()
Worksheets("PRICE SCHEDULE").Activate
Range("D15", "D181").Clear
Sheets("PRICE SCHEDULE").Select
End Sub

Sub Consolidate()

Worksheets("PRICE SCHEDULE").Range("G183").Select
Worksheets("PRICE SCHEDULE").Range("G183").Copy

Worksheets("Requisition Form").Activate

Worksheets("Requisition Form").Range("G27").Select
Worksheets("Requisition Form").Paste

Worksheets("PRICE SCHEDULE").Activate
Worksheets("PRICE SCHEDULE").Range("G27").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Values By Assignment

```vb
Sub Consolidate()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Price Schedule")
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Requisition Form")
   
    dws.Range("G27").Value = sws.Range("G183").Value
    dws.Range("H27").Value = "$1"

End Sub

Sub ClearCells()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Price Schedule")
    
    ws.Range("D15:D181").ClearContents
    'ws.Select ' only if it's necessary

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' start error-handling routine

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Price Schedule")
    If sws.AutoFilterMode Then sws.AutoFilterMode = False ' turn off AutoFilter
    Dim slCell As Range: Set slCell = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)
    If slCell.Row < 15 Then Exit Sub ' no data; 14 are the headers
    
    ' Reference the table range (has headers)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("D14", sws.Cells(slCell.Row, "F"))
    ' Reference the data range (no headers) to be used with 'Intersect'.
    Dim sdrg As Range: Set sdrg = srg.Resize(srg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    ' See the addresses in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G).
    Debug.Print "Table: " & srg.Address, "Data: " & sdrg.Address
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Requisition Form")
    ' This makes no sense since later the first cell could possibly be in row 27
    ' i.e. the range contains column 'G'.
    dws.Range("A27:H34").ClearContents
    Dim dfCell As Range
    Set dfCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    If dfCell.Row < 27 Then Set dfCell = dws.Range("G27")

    ' Copy
    
    With Application ' turn off settings
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    
    srg.AutoFilter 1, ">0", xlFilterValues ' filter on column D
    Intersect(sws.Range("D:D,F:F"), sdrg).Copy ' copy from columns D and F only
    dfCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ' paste values only
    srg.AutoFilter ' turn off auto filter

CleanExit: ' Exit Routine
    With Application
        If Not .EnableEvents Then ' settings are turned off; turn them on
            .EnableEvents = True
            .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        'Else ' settings are still turned on; do nothing
        End If
    End With
    Exit Sub ' don't forget this!
ClearError: ' continue error-handling routine
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & vbLf & Err.Description
    Resume CleanExit ' redirect to exit routine
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I quick thing. when I am clicking clear values button it is clearing the values but also the lines of that particular cells. I mean the boarder of those cells. Can you let me know why is it happening that way? your reply will be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `.Clear`, use `.ClearContents` to preserve the formatting.